# Is there any workaround to geckodriver's date input issue other than javascript?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automated-tests, geckodriver

So I'm using python + selenium + geckodriver and there is a known issue whereby send_keys method doesn't work with date input fields. I tried to use the following workaround:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('date').value='2016-11-05';")
```

and it sets the date correctly, but as soon as anything else happens on the page, the date resets back.
Is there any other reasonable way to do this?

The code of the field:

```
<input class="jss30" id="date" name="saveDate" type="date" value="2018-08-25">
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: It's only a guess, but do you need to include a carriage return in that date string to get it to "stick"?

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried to use  
document.getElementById('date').valueAsDate = new Date("2016-08-01");  
same result

Comment: WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath"));

        //Fill date as mm/dd/yyyy as 09/25/2013

        dateBox.sendKeys("09252013");

This is the java code which select the date from the datepicker and set it.

Comment: navigate to tested page, open Developer Tools in browser, and try to run `document.getElementById('date').value='2016-11-05'` in Console tab. Does it work? If not, that's your problem, nothing to do with selenium.